# Часы с помощью css и js

Tags: css, javascript

Как с помощью css и js можно сделать анимацию работающих часов подобным [этим](http://makepreview.ru/1217134433)

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите примеры: [раз](http://matthew.komputerwiz.net/2012/05/jscanvas-polar-clock/), [два](http://projects.joreteg.com/Polar-Clock-Canvas/), [три](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html).